# local time format in php

Tags: php, time, utc

I tried to post the StartRecordDateTime and EndRecordDateTime to a api.
2018-07-11T11:00:00Z is the utc time format. I wonder what is the format for local time melboune australia.

e.g. "2018-07-11T11:00:00 Australia/Melbourne" this will give me an error. Obviously, it depends on the api.

**My qeustion** is that do we have format like 2018-07-11T11:00:00Z **with the Z** at the end to indicate time zone for local time?

```
{
    "RecordDuration": "600000",
    "StartRecordDateTime": "2018-07-11T11:00:00Z",
    "EndRecordDateTime": "2018-07-11T11:10:00Z"
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and insert these codes:

$melbourne = new DateTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne');

$melbourneDT = new DateTime('your date time', $melbourne);